# Flutter Integration Testing- Is there any way to relaunch app while integration testing?

Tags: testing, flutter, integration-testing, flutter-test

I am trying to do flutter integration testing. As it stays on same screen when previous test executed. I need to relaunch app for testing from first/launch screen. Is there any way to relaunch app in flutter testing?

Comment: what do you mean first/launch screen. Do you mean you want to uninstall the app then install a new app and launch it?

Comment: That will be fine or just restarting app from test scripts also work for me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not possible with integration test but possible with a flutter driver. If your are ok with that you can check here:
https://arturkorobeynyk.medium.com/running-flutter-driver-tests-with-an-already-running-application-b7ae63f5c35e